# How to initialize digital output pin as low on arduino board??? I am getting lights on initially and i want lights off

Tags: arduino-uno

```
/*
Please note as I have used the android app you told , the string inputs are taken as
A,B,C,D,E,F,G and a,b,c,d,e,f,g.
I have also written code for voice on and off which has all on and all off function
but since the android app we are using dosent have such key so i didnt took them
*/

String inputs;
#define relay1 2 //Connect relay1 to pin 9
#define relay2 3 //Connect relay2 to pin 8
#define relay3 4 //Connect relay3 to pin 7
#define relay4 5 //Connect relay4 to pin 6
#define relay5 6 //Connect relay5 to pin 5
#define relay6 7 //Connect relay6 to pin 4
#define relay7 8 //Connect relay7 to pin 3
#define relay8 9 //Connect relay8 to pin 2

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600); //Set rate for communicating with phone
    pinMode(relay1, OUTPUT); //Set relay1 as an output
    pinMode(relay2, OUTPUT); //Set relay2 as an output
    pinMode(relay3, OUTPUT); //Set relay1 as an output
    pinMode(relay4, OUTPUT); //Set relay2 as an output
    pinMode(relay5, OUTPUT); //Set relay1 as an output
    pinMode(relay6, OUTPUT); //Set relay2 as an output
    pinMode(relay7, OUTPUT); //Set relay1 as an output
    pinMode(relay8, OUTPUT); //Set relay2 as an output
    digitalWrite(relay1, LOW); //Switch relay1 off
    digitalWrite(relay2, LOW); //Swtich relay2 off
    digitalWrite(relay3, LOW); //Switch relay1 off
    digitalWrite(relay4, LOW); //Swtich relay2 off
    digitalWrite(relay5, LOW); //Switch relay1 off
    digitalWrite(relay6, LOW); //Swtich relay2 off
    digitalWrite(relay7, LOW); //Switch relay1 off
    digitalWrite(relay8, LOW); //Swtich relay2 off
}
void loop()
{
    while(Serial.available()) //Check if there are available bytes to read
    {
        delay(10); //Delay to make it stable
        char c = Serial.read(); //Conduct a serial read
        if (c == '#'){
            break; //Stop the loop once # is detected after a word
        }
        inputs += c; //Means inputs = inputs + c
    }
    if (inputs.length() >0)
    {
        Serial.println(inputs);

        if(inputs == "A")
        {
            digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
        }
        else if(inputs == "a")
        {
            digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
        }
        else if(inputs == "B")
        {
            digitalWrite(relay2, LOW);
        }
        else if(inputs == "b")
        {
            digitalWrite(relay2, HIGH);
        }
        else if(inputs == "C")
        {
            digitalWrite(relay3, LOW);
        }
        else if(inputs == "c")
        {
            digitalWrite(relay3, HIGH);
        }
        else if(inputs == "D")
        {
            digitalWrite(relay4, LOW);
        }
        else if(inputs == "d")
        {
            digitalWrite(relay4, HIGH);
        }
        else if(inputs == "E")
        {
            digitalWrite(relay5, LOW);
        }
        else if(inputs == "e")
        {
            digitalWrite(relay5, HIGH);
        }
        else if(inputs == "F")
        {
            digitalWrite(relay6, LOW);
        }
        else if(inputs == "f")
        {
            digitalWrite(relay6, HIGH);
        }
        else if(inputs == "G")
        {
            digitalWrite(relay7, LOW);
        }
        else if(inputs == "g")
        {
            digitalWrite(relay7, HIGH);
        }
        else if(inputs == "H")
        {
            digitalWrite(relay8, LOW);
        }
        else if(inputs == "h")
        {
            digitalWrite(relay8, HIGH);
        }
        inputs="";
    }
}
```

Comment: some relay modules are active LOW

Comment: On the ralay, check if you see the text NC or NO. "Normally Close", means that you have to set HIGH if you want your lights ON. If you connect the lights on "Normally Open", if means that you have to set LOW if you want your lights ON.